# Phonegap Android AlarmManager plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, alarmmanager, phonegap-plugins

Is there a PhoneGap plugin to interact with the android AlarmManager api?

Comment: If you can do it natively, then it is really easy to make it a Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

You can schedule local notifications using above plugin